# 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this function) using android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am working on android-ndk in which i try to pass string from my C code to my java and then in activity. My codes are given below but i am getting the following errors. Please help me out here

```
#include <com_testing_ndk_FibLib.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Sample1_stringMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
        jstring string) {

    const char *name = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(string, NULL); //Java String to C Style string
    char msg[60] = "HelloWorld";
    jstring result;

    strcat(msg, name);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(string, name);
    puts(msg);
    result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(msg); // C style string to Java String
    return result;
}
```

Error log:

```
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c: In function 'Java_Sample1_stringMethod':
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:7:55: error: 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this function)
  const char *name = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(string, NULL); //Java String to C Style string
                                                       ^
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:7:55: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:7:21: error: too few arguments to function '(*env)->GetStringUTFChars'
  const char *name = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(string, NULL); //Java String to C Style string
                     ^
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:11:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcat'
  strcat(msg, name);
  ^
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:12:2: warning: passing argument 2 of '(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type
  (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(string, name);
  ^
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:12:2: note: expected 'jstring' but argument is of type 'const char *'
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:12:2: error: too few arguments to function '(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars'
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:14:11: warning: passing argument 1 of '(*env)->NewStringUTF' from incompatible pointer type
  result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(msg); // C style string to Java String
           ^
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:14:11: note: expected 'const struct JNINativeInterface **' but argument is of type 'char *'
jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:14:11: error: too few arguments to function '(*env)->NewStringUTF'
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/com_testing_ndk_FibLib/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.o] Error 1
```

My Java Code:

```
public class FibLib {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("com_testing_ndk_FibLib");
    }



     public static native String stringMethod(String text);

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
           System.loadLibrary("Sample1");
           FibLib sample = new FibLib();

           String  text   = sample.stringMethod("world");

           System.out.println("stringMethod: " + text);    
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All your JNI calls are missing the first parameter which should be `env`, as you're in compiling C code.

If your code was in C++, you could make calls like `env->NewStringUTF("xx")`. But in C, JNIEnv* isn't an object, hence you have to pass it as first argument, like so: `(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "xx")`

As for NULL being undefined, you can solve this by including the header that defines it: `#include <stddef.h>`

Comment: Wow, now I get it. so that env for "C" programs was hidden in so called functions category lol. Now I see it when I open that "functions" category....

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter does not seem to be optional:

```
jboolean iscopy;
const char *name = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(string, &iscopy);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i still getting the same error here. Please help me out.

Comment: I just had a look the the documentation. I'm not sure whether the second parameter is optional. I update my answer.